# Clear all views in tab layout?

Tags: android, view, android-tablelayout

I am creating an android application, in which I used tabs. There are six tabs which shows different activities. Last activity in tab have one button(clear). When we click on button, I want to clear all views in tab. Is it possible. Please guide me.

Comment: Clear.. What exactly? All the tabs? The 6th tab? More info please

Comment: i want clear all view data in all activities in tab

Answer (score 1):

Just Call another blank activity inside the onclick event of the button.

Comment: TabHost tabs = getTabHost();

Intent one = new Intent(this, one.class);
Intent two = new Intent(this, two.class);

TabSpec onespec = tabs.newTabSpec("");
onespec.setContent(one);
onespec.setIndicator("Number 1");

TabSpec twospec = tabs.newTabSpec("");
twospec.setContent(two);
twospec.setIndicator("Number 2");

tabs.addTab(onespec);
tabs.addTab(twospec);

Now on the two activity you can have the button and in the onclick call the activity with different Intent.

Comment: i want to clear all view data suppose textview has some data and edit text has some data clear textview and edit text data when click on button

Answer (score 0):

Try use Fragments instead of Activity for every tab, 
this way you could clear the tab much more quickly with `FragmentManager`

Comment: Can u give some tutorial for Fragments